# Drupal 7 Webforms linking hidden content with select option

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I have a webform for which I have created a custom module to create a Select Options list which dynamically generates from a database. I need use the selected option to pass hidden fields either through the original array which has been created or through a query.

The code I currently have is below, but I don't want to display SSA1 or SSA2 values but do want to pass the values to use in anayalsis-

```
function webform_options_webform_select_options_info() {
  $items = array();
  if (function_exists('_get_course_titles')) {
    $items['node_titles'] = array(
      'title' => t('Node titles'),
      'options callback' => '_get_course_titles',
    );
  }
  return $items;
}

function _get_course_titles() {
  $options = array();
  $sql = "SELECT code,instance, title, DATE_FORMAT(startdate,'%d-%m-%Y')startdate, enddate, days, SSA1, SSA2  FROM {ps9courses}";
  $row =  
  $result = db_query($sql);
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $options[$row->code] = $row->code.'-'. $row->instance.':'.$row->title.' ('.$row->startdate.', '.$row->days.')**'.$row->SSA1 .$row->SSA2;**
  }
  return $options;
}
```